# Add point or crosshair to center of Google earth engine timelapse

Tags: google-maps-markers, latitude-longitude, google-earth, google-earth-engine

Google earth engine allows me to view a timelapse of satellite imagery at specific (longitude, latitude) coordinates, e.g. https://earthengine.google.com/timelapse/#v=-9.16696,-58.55014,12,latLng, whose three arguments are latitude, longitude and zoom level.

Is it possible to modify the timelapse to include a marker, point or crosshair at its center -- in this example, at (latitude, longitude) = (-9.16696, -58.55014)?  How should I go about doing that?

Comment: As far as I know it is no possible. You should use a video editor instead.

Comment: I was hoping there'd be a solution involving https://code.earthengine.google.com/ -- I think that would work if the imagery used in the timelapses were available at https://code.earthengine.google.com/datasets.  Are you familiar with those?

Comment: I work with GEE, but directly with the API (Python in my case). I'm not familiar of using it without the API. If you have an account and access to the code editor, I can help you

Comment: I have access to the web-based editor at https://code.earthengine.google.com/.  I know how to center the map and display an image (and add a crosshair or point at the center), but I don't know whether the imagery used in https://earthengine.google.com/timelapse/#v=-9.16696,-58.55014,12,latLng is available.  Do you know whether it is (and, if so, what its collectio name is)?

Comment: You just need to know the coordinates of it. It says "Garimpo Juruena", so I guess that's it. And the collections are where it says "Data sources"... you can look at the IDs in https://code.earthengine.google.com/datasets. After that, if you need help with the code, I can help